# Graph theory & Feynman integrals

Tags: integration, graph-theory, quantum-field-theory

I am attending a course in Graph Theory and I am interested learning something about applications of this subject to Physics, especially I would like to learn something about Feynman integrals. Could you suggest me some books related to this topic? A friend suggest me to look at "Graph theory" by Nakanishi, has anyone read it? 
To be honest and allow you to recommend me the best book for my  mathematical background,  until now I have mainly been studying only Mathematics, not very much Phisics.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: [Not what you're asking for](http://fy.chalmers.se/~tfkhj/FeynmanIntegration.pdf), but too good to resist. :-)

Comment: @Lucian: Thanks for the article. This is the first time I see it and it is worth reading. However, if some suggestion comes to your mind regaring Feynman write to me again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the book $\textit{Feynman Motives}$ by Matilde Marcolli. Its not exactly an introduction to the subject itself but gives a great picture of where the connection between Feynman integrals and graphs can lead.

Comment: @ Dori Bejleri: Thanks for the suggestion. I will definetely try it.

Comment: Does anyone have other suggestions? Thanks for the help.